# Infopath Logic Inspector is blank

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath, sharepoint-online

The Infopath Logic Inspector does not show any information, running either infopath 2010 (on prem Enterprise) or infopath 2013 (sharepoint online) from windows 7. This is a recent occurrence.

This is the case for existing as well as new forms.
See attached - this is a new form with a rule but the Logic Inspector pane is blank.

It occurs on many machines.

It may be related to Microsoft Updates - here's a report linking it with a changed icon in the date picker and KB3192391.
http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/31763/108261.aspx

The date picker is not a problem, but the blank Logic Inspector certainly is.

[image: Screen print - the rules for this field do not appear in Logic Inspector]

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

```
Internet Options -> Security -> Trusted Site
```

Add:

```
about:internet
```

You may need to uncheck require server verification for https.

Source: http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/t/31763.aspx?PageIndex=2